# Alternative Voronoi diagram with specified minimum number of samples in each cell

Tags: python, scipy, cell, voronoi

I'm using the `scipy.spatial.Voronoi` function to bin up my data where the cell sizes decrease with increased 2D point density, in Python.

However the function places cell boundaries around each point such that each cell can only contain one point. (This is the point of a Voronoi diagram anyway)

However, is there a way to specify a minimum number of samples to lie in each bin such that you still have smaller cells in over-dense regions but no cell contains only one point?

Link to the function in question: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html

Example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d

vor = Voronoi(xy.T)
fig = voronoi_plot_2d(vor, show_vertices=False, line_colors='orange',
                 line_width=2, line_alpha=0.6, point_size=2)
```

Note: `xy` can be any stacked x and y coordinate array of points here.

[image]

Perhaps there's an alternative algorithm entirely for this task? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what do you _really_ want, in the end? It's not a Voronoi diagram, it's... what?

Comment: I would like points to fall in cells, which get smaller as the 2D point density increases, but where each cell must contain a specified minimum number of data points. So I'd call that an adaptive 2D boundary diagram or something similar?

Comment: you could join Voronoi cells, but (a) there is no clear criterion for chosing _which_ cells to join (b) you generally end up with cells that are not convex

Comment: Would you be happy with a lower limit on cell area, instead of an upper limit on points within a cell? Would you be OK with cells of any (connected) shape?

Comment: You could try my php implementation:https://tetramatrix.github.io/awvd/.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weighted Voronoi Diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51983360/weighted-voronoi-diagram)

Comment: this is NOT a duplicate of the Weighted Voronoi Diagram question, since that is only ONE of the possible ways to answer the OP's question, and, as long as the OP does not change their mind, not the preferred one!